# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre un main con argumentos y otro sin argumentos en c++?

Tags: c++

Hay un main que es así.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

}
```

Y otro que es simplemente así:

```
int main(){

  }
```

Hasta ahora he usado los dos y ambos me han funcionado, así que no he identificado cuál es la diferencia entre usar uno u otro, o si tienen propositos diferentes.

Comment: En el primer `main` argc: alamacena la cantidad de parametros contando con el nombre del ejecutable.
argv[]: Un arreglo que contiene todos los parametros recibidos. si usted acostumbra a usar la terminal muchas veces haces cosas como esta: `miPrograma argumento` es ahi cuando atravez del primer main puede obtener esos parametros y usarlos dentro de su programa para generar un comportamiento u otro, comprobar que parametro se le paso, o la cantidad de parametros que se le han pasado al ejecutar su programa ect. P.D: *argv[]: array de punteros a caracteres.Saludos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En el primer `main`

- argc: almacena la cantidad (numero) de parametros, contando con el nombre del ejecutable.
- *argv[]: *Un arreglo que contiene todos los parametros recibidos*<sup>1</sup> contando con el nombre del ejecutable.

si usted acostumbra a usar la terminal muchas veces haces cosas como esta:

```
miPrograma argumento1 argumento2
```

es ahí cuando a través del primer `main` pero NO del segundo, puede obtener esos **parámetros** y usarlos dentro de su programa para generar un comportamiento u otro, comprobar que parametro se le pasó, o la cantidad de parámetros que se le han pasado al ejecutar su programa ect.

puede compilar este ejemplo:

---

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("numero de argumentos: %i\n", argc);

    printf("Argumento 0: %s\n", argv[0]);
    printf("Argumento 1: %s\n", argv[1]);
    printf("Argumento 2: %s\n", argv[2]);
    printf("Argumento 3: %s\n", argv[3]);
    return 0;
}
```

y ejecutarlo así por ejemplo:

```
a.out stack overflow es
```

Shell:

```
./a.out stack overflow es
numero de argumentos: 4
Argumento 0: ./a.out
Argumento 1: stack
Argumento 2: overflow
Argumento 3: es
```

(si su programa se llama a.out)

---

el siguiente codigo usa esta sintaxis `char **argv` en lugar de `char *argv[]` pero "basicamente" es lo mismo. Una es mas de c y otra de c++, algunos lo llaman *una matriz bidimensional de caracteres* y otros *array de punteros a caracteres*.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("Argumento 0: %s\n", argv[0]);
    printf("Argumento 1: %s\n", argv[1]);
    printf("Argumento 2: %s\n", argv[2]);
    printf("Argumento 3: %s\n", argv[3]);
    return 0;
}
```

<sup>1</sup> *argv[]: array de punteros a caracteres.

Answer (score 2):

> ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre un main con argumentos y otro sin argumentos en c++?

La propia pregunta tiene la respuesta: Los argumentos. Ambas versiones serán consideradas el punto de entrada del programa.

---

Según el [estándar de C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) (traducción mía):

> #### 3.6.1 Función main
>
> 1. El programa deberá contener una función global llamada `main`, que será el punto de inicio del programa. [...]
> 2. La implementación no debe predefinir la función `main`. Esta función no debe ser sobrecargada. Debe declararse con un valor de retorno `int` [...] La implementación debe permitir ambas firmas
>
>    2.1. - una función `()` devolviendo `int` y
>
>    2.2. - una función `(int,` puntero a puntero a `char)` devolviendo `int`
>
>    como el tipo de `main`.

Así pues, ambas firmas son correctas y válidas para `main` y el estándar no indica que ninguna de las versiones de `main` deba actuar de manera diferente.

Answer (score 1):

Ambas formas son validas y son el punto de entrada para tu aplicación.

La primera forma `int main(int argc, char** argv)` recibe los argumentos de linea de comando (cuando se lanza la aplicación), en forma de: arreglo de cadenas terminadas en NULL (argv) y la cantidad de cadenas en ese arreglo (argc).

La segunda forma `int main()` es mas simple, la preferida cuando la aplicación no necesita leer los argumentos de linea de comando (ej, no los usa)

Aunque no lo has mencionado, `main` debe retornar un 0 si ejecución fue exitosa y distinto de 0 si hubo una falla. Si omites el `return`, c++ asume que retornaste 0 (o sea éxito).