# ¿Cómo convierto char* a std::wstring?

Tags: c++, c++11

Necesito capturar las palabras que entran en

```
 int main( int argc, char**argv )
```

y pasarlo a un `std::wstring`
¿Qué función existe en el standar c++11?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se si dice esto: *Necesito capturar las palabras que entran en...*.

para poner en contexto "imagino que si" o es que no sabe como capturar esos valores, si es lo segundo, un usuario hizo un [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/55115/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-un-main-con-argumentos-y-otro-sin-argumentos-en-c) hace poco que lo puede ayudar.

pienso que esto lo puede ayudar:

```
#include <iostream>       
#include <string>         
#include <locale>         
#include <codecvt>        

#include <locale>

int main ()
{

  //simulacion
  char const * argv[] = {"España", "Argentina -> En unión y libertad"};

  typedef std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t> contype;
  std::wstring_convert<contype, wchar_t> conver;

  std::wstring str = conver.from_bytes(argv[0]);
  std::wstring str1 = conver.from_bytes(argv[1]);

  //esto lo dejo en base a sus preguntas anteriores
  std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
  std::wcout.imbue(std::locale("en_US.UTF-8"));

  std::wcout <<  str << std::endl ;
  std::wcout <<  str1;

  return 0;
}
```

---

- [wstring_convert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/wstring_convert/)
- [wstring](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/wstring/)
- [codecvt_utf8](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/codecvt/codecvt_utf8/)

Comment: Claro, cuando uno pasa los argumentos al ejecutable, esos argumentos son capturados con el formato de un arreglo de char const*. Mi idea es transformar esos char const* a wstring. Probé tu ejemplo, la cabecera <codecvt> no se encuentra en gcc-4.9.4, por lo que no puedo usar el `codecvt_utf8`. Gracias por responder @AngelAngel

Comment: [Desde GCC 5.1](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.1.0/libstdc++/manual/manual/facets.html#std.localization.facet.codecvt/) esta característica está habilitada. Yo lo probé con [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) que tiene un g++ 6.3.0. Y funcionó

Comment: @EmanuelGauler gracias por la info sobre las versiones. Saludos