# nombre del fichero (c++)

Tags: c++

Me ha surgido una duda:

¿Como puedo hacer o modificar este subprograma para que cuando yo introduzca el nombre del fichero como parámetro de entrada, me dé esto nombre.txt?

Adjunto el Subprograma aqui:

```
void guardar_fic(string nom_fic){
   ofstream entrada;
   entrada.open("nom_fic.txt");
   entrada<<"EOO"<<endl;
   entrada.close();
}
```

**Pd:** En el caso de poner por ejemplo; `guardar_fic(PEPE)` me cree el fichero como `PEPE.txt`

Gracias.

Comment: no tengo muy claro lo que pregunta, pero quizas lo que busca es algo asi: `entrada.open(nom_fic + ".txt");` donde nom_fic es el parametro de entrada de la funcion guardar. o quizas esto otro -> https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/55115/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-un-main-con-argumentos-y-otro-sin-argumentos-en-c/ usar los argumentos de entrada a su programa. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Lo que creo que podrías hacer es

```
nom_fic += ".txt";
ofstream entrada;
entrada.open(nom_fic.c_str());
entrada<<"EOO"<<endl;
entrada.close();
```

Inténtalo a ver si te funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Consulta los [constructores de `std::ofstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream):

`basic_ofstream()`

Crea un flujo de datos de escritura a archivo que no apunta a ningún archivo.

`explicit basic_ofstream(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode = ios_base::out)`

Crea un flujo de datos de escritura a archivo que apunta al archivo cuyo nombre está almacenado en el arreglo de caracteres recibido como primer parámetro.

`explicit basic_ofstream(const std::filesystem::path::value_type*, std::ios_base::openmode = ios_base::out)`

Crea un flujo de datos de escritura a archivo que apunta al archivo que está en la ruta recibida como primer parámetro.

`explicit basic_ofstream( const std::string&, std::ios_base::openmode = ios_base::out)`

Crea un flujo de datos de escritura a archivo que apunta al archivo cuyo nombre está almacenado en la cadena recibida como primer parámetro.

`explicit basic_ofstream( const std::filesystem::path&, std::ios_base::openmode = ios_base::out)`

Crea un flujo de datos de escritura a archivo que apunta al archivo que está en la ruta recibida como primer parámetro.

---

Así que puedes abrir un archivo con un `std::string`, por lo tanto tu función quedaría así:

```
void guardar_fic(std::string nom_fic){
   if (std::ofstream entrada{nom_fic + ".txt"}) {
       entrada << "EOO\n";
   }
   // No es necesario llamar a entrada.close,
   // se llama automáticamente al salir del if.
}
```